# Run excel file once a day even if user didnt open the file

Tags: database, vba, excel

I have difficult task to do. I have a excel database that should once a day check if some of the elements doesn't expire (and if so send an email with notofication). Is it possible to write VBa scirpt that will fires once a day and if necessary start an excel file? or alternatively does windows 7 allow something like a cron with php? so that it will start the file and the Vba script will send the notofications?

I know that probably excel is not a perfect working environmante to do that, but its not my idea, only my problem to slove.

Greetings

Comment: this question is probably better suitable on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com)

Comment: I think you could do this with a cron script and then adjust the macro to fire when the book gets opened.  and this is a good question but its probably down voted because you haven't showed us anything you have tried yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can open an Excel worksheet by using a shell script like this:

```
Shell("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\Excel.exe" myfile.xlsm, vbNormalFocus)
```

Here is a [tutorial](http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/shell.htm) on using shell scripts in VBA.